# How to access ServerUrl when sitecore website setup in clustered enviroment

Tags: scaling

We have set up two CD server( http://cds1mysite.com & http://cds2mysite.com ) in clustered environment where redirection to these URLs handled by LoadBalancer. Website public URL is https://www.mysite.com 
So If we use following code to get server URL it's returning CD server URL not public URL. Instead it should return https://www.mysite.com

```
string serverurl = Sitecore.Globals.ServerUrl;
```

Do we have any other way to access public URL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you already specified the hostname in the site definition configuration file.

You can get the hostname by calling

`Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName` or `Sitecore.Context.Site.TargetHostName`.

if you have a list of sites domain delimited by `|`, it will return you all the values from the `hostName` attribute.

Then you can split by `|` to get the different sites URL. If you specify the targetHostName attribute as https://www.mysite.com, then you can make use of the TargetHostName.

**Proposed Solution 1**

You can either change the position of the urls in the hostName from

```
hostName="cms.mysite.com|www.mysite.com|33.44.54.123"
```

to

```
hostName="www.mysite.com|cms.mysite.com|33.44.54.123"
```

Then when you split, you take the first one.

**Proposed Solution 2**

Make use of the targetHostName in your SiteDefinition.config as follows:

```
hostName="cms.mysite.com|www.mysite.com|33.44.54.123"
targetHostName="www.mysite.com"
```

Then, make use of the code

```
var url = Sitecore.Context.Site.TargetHostName;
```

**EDIT 1**

It is better to not use Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName but Sitecore.Context.Site.TargetHostName because the HostName property is ok while you one have only one Hostname per site in the web.config.

The TargetHostName take the property TargetHostName of the site if specified in the site tag of the web.config or the first hostname if this property is not specified.

Reference: http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/dont-use-hostname.html?m=1

Comment: actually in sitedefinitation.config file we have only following hostname attribute not targethostname
hostName="cms.mysite.com|cmsmysite.us|33.44.54.123"
so I won't get if I use Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName

well why we need targethostname if we have hostname attribute

Comment: This attribute targethostname will be used by the SiteResolver if it is not blank. It will use the HostName. By default targetHostName is blank. So you can use Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName and since you have delimited it by pipe, you will need to check into the SiteResolver

Comment: as you mentioned targethostname will be used by SiteResolver but as I don't have targethostname attribute so I won't get any thing. Am I correct here?

Other option I'm thinking about put the https://www.mysite.com text in Settings.config file and directly access through in code by settings code.How is it?

Comment: Why would you not able to retrieve the hostname? Since you have specified the HostName, you can use the Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName

Comment: first of all I just want to correct hostname and it's hostName="cms.mysite.com|www.mysite.com|33.44.54.123" so If I use Sitecore.Context.Site.HostName I got "cms.mysite.com|www.mysite.com|33.44.54.123" Did you mean that I should get this string seperated by pipe and where I get www fetch that string from array. Is it?

Comment: Please see the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52558/discussion-between-sukhi-and-hishaam-namooya).